# MySQL Query Taking 5 Minutes to Execute

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, query-optimization

I am very new to MySQL and am trying to use LEFT Joins for the first time. While the results that are returned are what is expected the time the query takes is far too long.

I have 3 tables that I am joining and when I run the queries separately the data is returned in 0.0002 seconds. With a join the query takes up to 300 seconds.

evmbd has 6012 rows that I need to return and I just want one column from both the xlba and 3pla tables to be joined on the naa

I have been reading up on optimizing LEFT JOIN queries and have added in INDEX on all 3 tables on the naa columns.

```
SELECT e.cluster,e.vm,e.TotalCapacityGB,e.naa,p.array,x.array
FROM evmbd AS e
LEFT JOIN xlba AS x ON x.naa like replace(e.naa,'naa.','') AND x.date = (select max(date) from xlba ) 
LEFT JOIN 3pla AS p ON p.naa = replace(e.naa,'naa.','') AND p.date = (select max(date) from 3pla )
WHERE e.date = (select max(date) from evmbd)  
GROUP BY e.cluster, e.vm 
ORDER BY e.cluster, e.vm
```

Any help would be amazing as well as any documentation on advanced queries

Comment: uuuu baby.... `subselect` in where, `join` not by key but by a `like`, which actually doesnt need to be a `like` because there is no `%`, also subselects inside join conditions... man are you trying to make it slow on purpose ?!

Comment: hahaha @TuncayGöncüoğlu nahhh I just have no idea what I am doing :(

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu the like was left over from testing i had been doing, it ran slow with it there or not. What should I be looking at for this query?

Comment: I upvoted Rodrigo A.'s answer below. He has the right idea. However, on top of that, I would look into your `3pla`  and `xlba` table structure to see if the joins could be done over an integer key field instead of a string search plus a date.

Comment: uuuu -- we don't have any idea what you are doing either.  Please try to describe what the query needs to do.  And what kind of  data is in `naa` and `array`.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Lack of one is reason to block answers. Particularly--DDL & EXPLAIN. Which MySQL? Statistics? Etc etc.

Comment: Literally dozens of textbook pdfs are free online with chapters on query implementation/optimization/performance, let alone entire books & other resources. But you need to learn straightforward clear design to appreciate all but the most simple practices. So google for basic practices. Read everything in the MySQL documentation re optimization & indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your tables but maybe this could be helpful:

```
DECLARE @MAX_XLBA DATETIME
DECLARE @MAX_3PLA DATETIME
DECLARE @MAX_EVMBD DATETIME

SET @MAX_XLBA = (select max(date) from xlba)
SET @MAX_3PLA = (select max(date) from 3pla)
SET @MAX_EVMBD = (select max(date) from evmbd)

SELECT e.cluster,e.vm,e.TotalCapacityGB,e.naa,p.array,x.array
FROM evmbd AS e
LEFT JOIN xlba AS x ON x.naa = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(e.naa,4,15))) AND x.date = @MAX_XLBA
LEFT JOIN 3pla AS p ON p.naa = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(e.naa,4,15))) AND p.date = @MAX_3PLA
WHERE e.date = @MAX_EVMBD
```

Maybe if the dates are not calculated at the time the query is running, the performance could be better. Same for the replace you were doing.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

When you join on the replace function, then it has to evaluate every row with the replace to see if it matches.  That is making you select every record, then run the replace.  Additionally, when your second comparison is a subselect using a field from the current row.  So, for every possible row in e, you are testing against every row in x, and for every one of those, you are testing against every row of p.  And for every single one of x*e*p you are also running another select query.  You are certainly giving the server a workout.  There are a bunch of things you can do to speed this up.

1. Make the naa fields consistent across all the tables.  Remove the "naa." on e, or add it to the others, so you can do a direct comparison, instead of a like or replace function.
2. prefetch the max dates you need instead of running subselects. Rodrigo had the right idea on that.
3. If you can't do either of those, select the truncated values and matching dates into temp tables, and run your select with joins off of that.

Doing #1 will probably eliminate most of the slowdown, but it depends on how many rows are matching your joins.

For #2
In Rodrigo's post, he gave an example of this, but you don't need the trim functions. Also, for optimum performance, you should index the date field as well.

```
SET @MAX_XLBA = (select max(date) from xlba) 
SET @MAX_3PLA = (select max(date) from 3pla) 
SET @MAX_EVMBD = (select max(date) from evmbd) 
SELECT e.cluster,e.vm,e.TotalCapacityGB,e.naa,p.array,x.array FROM evmbd AS e 
   LEFT JOIN xlba AS x ON x.naa = e.naa AND x.date = @MAX_XLBA 
   LEFT JOIN 3pla AS p ON p.naa = e.naa AND p.date = @MAX_3PLA 
   WHERE e.date = @MAX_EVMBD
```

Comment: Just removing the naa. from the one table has dropped it from 300 seconds to 10. Thanks for that tip.I am not sure how to complete the prefetch of max dates. Where do you do this?

Answer (score -1):

For projects with huge data amounts I got the same problem in SQLite. Too many joins is slowing down the program a lot. There, I used following solutions:

1. You have 2 left-joins in the code, please keep the one with the most effect. The other one you can calculate in memory after getting the result.

2. Make a subset in a temporary table. Then calculate the other join.

Comment: downvoted: a) it is not sqlite, it is mysql, as noted in tags. b) advise 1 is unnecessary. c) advise 2: see previous point. d) advise 3 SHOULD BE AVOIDED COMPLETELY, it really is a much bigger headache with database consistency in long run. e) advise 4 is not applicable. well, mysql does have buffer settings too, but defaults are usually ok. f) DO NOT USE MYISAM, STICK TO INNODB for any table you need concurrent access, transactions, stability etc. In fact, you know what, dont use MYISAM AT ALL.

Comment: Let's stick to solution 1 and 2. I removed the others above. Thanks for helping out.